# uninstalling windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

I installed windows 8 straight onto vista xp and I don't like windows 8 wish to uninstall but keeps telling me missing files but have triple checked none are missing even tried restoring computer to date before install of 8 without joy I am getting very frustrated and I feel like just tossing computer which is not viable as cant afford to replace it the computer is 2 yrs old all old files are in file in c drive so they are still there please please help me this is depressing me bad this has slowed down my computer a lot

Comment: You will need to format the hdd in order to install `Windows Vista` or `Windows XP` there is no way to "uninstall" `Windows 8` at this point.   I must ask what you mean by the term "vista xp".  Please edit your question with this clarification.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It being an ADHD doesn't explain anything. The author will have to backup his files and format the HDD if he wants to install `Windows Vista` or `Windows XP` on this system.

Answer (score 2):

If you say that your files are still on the `C` drive, then I suggest you to backup the whole drive on an external hard disk and reinstall the former OS you had using the discs that should have come with your PC when you bought it.

Comment: Also, it's probably a good idea to create a separate data partition and start using that, while you are at it. That way, it will be much easier to both backup and restore files later on.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling that is a useful suggestion, but unfortunately it wouldn't help for data backup: if the hard disk fails for whatever reason, the data would be lost even if residing on a different partition. It is always better to backup on an external destination.

Comment: I did not say backup **to** the second partition. I know that's essentially useless against anything but fat finger errors (for which essentially any backup scheme will do). But keeping one's data files (documents, email, pictures etc) on a separate partition means it's possible to reformat the system drive and start over with a clean installation while retaining the data, with minimal hassle. And I personally like to keep applications and data on separate file systems (partitions in Windows parlace).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling that's why I said it was a useful suggestion :) Since in your comment you mentioned the backup of the files I thought that you were referring to actual backup.